# how to use Redux-form selector : getFormMeta

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have Radio Group component and which internally calls Radio component, I need to access the form meta info in at Radio Group level to be able to check and perform the necessary validation. One thing I came across is getFormMeta selector, but not sure how to use, any working example would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`getFormMeta` is a higher order function that takes in the name of the form to connect to and returns a function of type `(state) => formMeta`.

Since the the props given to a Field's component include the form name, you could then make use of the `getFormMeta` selector as follows inside your RadioGroup component file:

```
import { getFormMeta } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

...

class RadioGroup extends Component {
    ...
}

...

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    const formName = ownProps.meta.form;
    const metaSelector = getFormMeta(formName);

    return {
        formMeta: metaSelector(state)
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RadioGroup);
```